# How to make CodenameOne's RadioButton respect its image constants on its pressed state?

Tags: codenameone

I'm not sure if this is a bug or just something I'm missing.

I've added 2 multi-images to the constants "RadioSelectedImage" and "RadioUnselectedImage", and they work fine except in their pressed state. For example: the custom image I added to the unselected constant appears just fine in my RadioButton before any interaction, but when I press it, the image changes to the native image, and when I release it, it changes to my custom selected image as expected.

I thought the problem was with RadioButton's pressed UIID, but I don't see anything that could be changing its image. I'm deriving everything in the pressed state from the unselected state.

Furthermore, if I set the constant "IncludeNativeBool" to false, then it all works as expected, and my custom image appears even in the pressed state. I'd rather not do that though, since I rely on the native theme for some components in my app.

Am I missing something here or is this a bug? If it's the latter, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `radioSelectedImage`, `radioUnselectedImage`, `radioSelectedFocusImage` & `radioUnselectedFocusImage`.

Comment: I can't find the last two constants you mentioned in the theme's drop-down list. I noticed that there was an updated version of the Netbeans plugin, but even after updating, I can't find them. I only see radioSelectedImage, radioUnselectedImage, radioSelectedDisImage & radioUnselectedDisImage (for the disabled states, I presume). As a sidenote, I noticed this also happens with CheckBoxes, and setting IncludeNativeBool to false also solves the issue for them.

Comment: The same thing is true for both. Just paste the value into place, the combo box is editable and avoid setting the includeNativeBool to false since that has a LOT of implications.

Comment: That worked. Many thanks! Just out of curiosity, is there some place where I can check the full list of constants, or is that combo box it and they just didn't make it to the list yet?

Comment: Some are mentioned in the developer guide but there are a lot of those that get added all the time and sometimes we can't keep everything in line with development.